# How to filter based on string in hive

Tags: hive

So, I have a table of following schema

```
user_id int,
movie_id int,
score   float,
demography string
```

the demography is a comma delimited string 
like `'m,22,ca,.....'`. This can have variable number of elements in it.

Now, I want to filter the records based on certain characterstics...
which is if demography is "m" or is from "ca" etc etc..
So, currently what I am doing is..

split the string into array `(split(table.demography, "\\,"))` and then `explode` it and do the filter.. using a where clause..

```
Where exploded_demography = 'm' or exploded_demography='ca' (etc etc)
```

But, explode causes the records to.. well.. explode.. I am trying to avoid that as it seems to bloat up the number of records..

Is there a way I can do this without exploding the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
find_in_set('ca', table.demography) > 0
```

From: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions

> int find_in_set(string str, string strList) Returns the first
>   occurance of str in strList where strList is a comma-delimited string.
>   Returns null if either argument is null. Returns 0 if the first
>   argument contains any commas. For example, find_in_set('ab',
>   'abc,b,ab,c,def') returns 3.